# Function like "when" but returns a value?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, option-type

Is there a way to write this more concisely? I have many functions that look like this. Each of them has some boolean condition, which then either return a value or `Nothing`

```
rootMiddleware :: Application -> Application
rootMiddleware app req respond =
    fromMaybe next . fmap respond $
          serveIndex ["questionnaire"] "../app/answer/answer.html" req
      <|> serveIndex ["survey"] "../app/builder/builder.html" req
      <|> redirect [] "/survey/forms" req

  where
    next = app req respond

serveIndex :: [Text] -> FilePath -> Request -> Maybe Response
serveIndex prefix fp req =
    if prefix `isPrefixOf` pathInfo req
      then Just $ responseFile status200 [("Content-Type", "text/html")] fp Nothing
      else Nothing

redirect :: [Text] -> ByteString -> Request -> Maybe Response
redirect pathParts url req =
    if pathParts == pathInfo req
      then Just $ redirectTo url
      else Nothing
```

[`when`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when) is really close, but it doesn't let you return a value in the applicative. Is there something equivalent for this case?

Comment: Seems pretty concise to me already, you could use `bool :: Bool -> a -> a -> a` instead of `if .. then .. else` if you find that more appealing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `guard`:

```
guard :: Alternative f => Bool -> f ()
guard c = if c then pure () else empty
```

Then you can rewrite

```
if c then Just x else Nothing
```

as

```
x <$ guard c
```

When you're not going straight to `Just`, consider

```
guard c *> e
```

which works very well with `do` notation as well. Thanks to Daniel Wagner for the `<$` expression.

Note also that

```
fromMaybe x . fmap f
```

is better written

```
maybe x f
```

Comment: [`guard`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) doesn't use the notorious `fail`. It used to use `mzero`, but since AMP it has been generalized to use `Alternative`'s `empty`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, oops! Glad to hear it.

Comment: I prefer to define `(<?>) :: Alternative f => Bool -> f a -> f a; True  <?> x = x; False <?> x = empty`, so instead of `x <$ guard c` we can write `c <?> pure x`, which looks more self-descriptive to me. `mfilter` can be of use too.